# Data is not submitting through Ajax is not Submitting

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

here is ajax code

$('#form').on('submit', function(e){

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value,
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
             type : 'POST', 
             url: "{% url 'HealthTest' %}",
             data: {
              first_name : $('#first_name').val(),
              deparment : $('#deparment').val(),
              Reg_No : $('#Reg_No').val(),
              Health_status : $('#Health_status').val(),
              dataType: "json",
             },

             success: function(data){
                $('#output').html(data.msg) /* response message */
             },
      
             failure: function() {
             }
            });
```

});

This form code

{% csrf_token %}{{form.as_p}}

when i press submit in my pages this error message pop up in console window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL0Qu.png)

I Tried different solution but it is not working for me. I am new to this Thank in advance.

Comment: A 500 error code means that your server side code is having a problem, not the JS. Also note that you don't call `e.preventDefault()` in your JS so the form is being submit normally, not through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

First configure the urls.py:

```
from .views import functionpost

urlpatterns = [
    path('<url>', functionpost),
]
```

On Python views.py side:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def functionpost(self, request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {'informations':{'info1': request.POST['information_1']}, 
                   'info2': request.POST['iformation_2']}
        return JsonResponse(context)
```

On html the post forms goes:

```
<form id="post-form" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="input-group form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
         id="information_1">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
         id="information_2">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="main-btn">Button</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"<intire_url>", 
    data: {
        information1:$('#information_1').val(),
        information2:$('#information_2').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.informations['info1'] + data.informations['info2']);
        }
   });
```